# Log4j2: how to filter out messages having not ThreadContext key?

Tags: filter, log4j2

In my application, sometimes I have a threadContext key `jobId` when logging, sometimes not.

So I want to pass log messages to my JDBC log appender (which requires the field `jobId`) only if the key `jobId` is present in the `ThreadContext`.

I can not manage it to configure the `DynamicThresholdFilter` so that log message are skipped.

```xml
<JDBC name="databaseAppender" tableName="LOG_MESSAGE">
    <DynamicThresholdFilter key="jobId" 
                            defaultThreshold="INFO" 
                            onMatch="ACCEPT"
                            onMismatch="DENY">
    </DynamicThresholdFilter>
    <DataSource jndiName="java:jboss/datasources/myDS" />
    <Column name="MESSAGE" pattern="%message" />
    <Column name="Job_KEY_" pattern="%X{jobId}" />
</JDBC>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [RoutingAppender](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#RoutingAppender) to do this, similar to an [example](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#separate_log_files) on the [log4j2 FAQ page](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html).

Here's a Java class that does some logging:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext;

public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args){

        //These should appear in the console only
        log.debug("No jobId, This is some debug!");
        log.info("No jobId, Here's some info!");
        log.error("No jobId, Some error happened!");

        //These should route to a simulated JDBC appender only
        ThreadContext.put("jobId", "1234");
        log.debug("With jobId, This is some debug!");
        log.info("With jobId, Here's some info!");
        log.error("With jobId, Some error happened!");

        //Once again these will go to console only
        ThreadContext.remove("jobId");
        log.debug("No jobId, This is some debug!");
        log.info("No jobId, Here's some info!");
        log.error("No jobId, Some error happened!");
    }
}
```

Here's a sample log4j2.xml configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>

        <File name="simulatedJdbc" fileName="logs/simulatedJdbc.txt"
            immediateFlush="false" append="true">
            <PatternLayout
                pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} %X{jobId} - %msg%n" />
        </File>


        <Routing name="Routing">
            <Routes pattern="$${ctx:jobId}">
                <!-- This route is chosen if ThreadContext has no value for key jobId. -->
                <Route key="$${ctx:jobId}" ref="Console" />
                <!-- This is the default route when no others match -->
                <Route ref = "simulatedJdbc"/>              
            </Routes>
        </Routing>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Routing" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The result of running the above is the following output:

**Console output:**

```
17:49:41.659 [main] DEBUG example.SomeClass - No jobId, This is some debug!
17:49:41.663 [main] INFO  example.SomeClass - No jobId, Here's some info!
17:49:41.664 [main] ERROR example.SomeClass - No jobId, Some error happened!
17:49:41.664 [main] DEBUG example.SomeClass - No jobId, This is some debug!
17:49:41.664 [main] INFO  example.SomeClass - No jobId, Here's some info!
17:49:41.664 [main] ERROR example.SomeClass - No jobId, Some error happened!
```

**simulatedJdbc.txt output:**

```
2019-02-08 17:49:41.664 [main] DEBUG example.SomeClass 1234 - With jobId, This is some debug!
2019-02-08 17:49:41.664 [main] INFO  example.SomeClass 1234 - With jobId, Here's some info!
2019-02-08 17:49:41.664 [main] ERROR example.SomeClass 1234 - With jobId, Some error happened!
```

As you can see, when the `ThreadContext` contains `jobId` the logs are routed to the simulated JDBC appender (just a file appender in my example). When the `jobId` is missing logs are routed to the console appender instead.

Hope this helps!